# How to render an element (React Class) an arbitrary number of times?

Tags: reactjs

I have two components:

```
var kBoard = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {numCols: 0};
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        //simplified
        this.setState({numCols: 3});
    },
    render: function () {
        return(
            <div className="kBoard">
                I'm a board
                //TODO: insert columns
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var kColumn = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='kColumn'>
                I'm a column
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Where it says `//TODO: insert columns`, I want to insert a number of `Column` components equal to `this.state.numCols`.

I tried a simple for loop, but after learning more about how JSX compiles to JS I understand why that won't work. I feel like I should probably be using `map` somehow, but I haven't been able to get it right yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React accepts an array of elements, so you can create it using a for or while loops, or `Array.prototype.map`. You can also use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create a new array of length x, and populate it with columns:

```
render: function () {
    return(
        <div className="kBoard">
            I'm a board
            {
                Array.from({ length: this.state.numCols }, (v, k) => <kColumn key={ k } />)
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Note - react components name should start with a capital case - kColumn -> KColumn.

Comment: This is working perfectly, but I am getting an (inconsequential?) error in the console that says every child in the array should have a unique `key` prop. I tried doing `<kColumn key={()} />` with no effect. Is there a way to also map index locations as unique key values with `Array.from`? I changed the map function to `(x,y) => <kColumn key={y} />` and the error went away but I honestly can't tell from the generated HTML if it worked or not.

Comment: It's not inconsequential. Elements in arrays should have keys to help react in [elements reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html), which actually means - helping react in re-rendering less on updates. See edited answer.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! This is my first React project, that link looks like one I should read now.

Comment: Welcome. Stupid oversight on my part :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array  where every element's value is it's index, and then map that to an array of columns, to get a new column for each index. Use the index property to set the key of the column

```
render: function () {

    var i= 0, arr = [];

    // Fill the array with the indexes
    for (i = 0; i < this.state.numCols; i += 1) {
        arr[i] = i;        
    }

    return(
        <div className="kBoard">
            I'm a board
            {arr.map(function(i) {
                return <kColumn key={i} />
            });}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var kBoard = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {numCols: 0};
},
componentDidMount: function(){
    //simplified
    this.setState({numCols: 3});
},
render: function () {
    return(
        <div className="kBoard">
            {
               this.state.numCols.map(function(result,i) {
                 return <kColumn key={i} />;
               })
            }
            //TODO: insert columns
        </div>
    );
}
});
```